# Unable to understand the way of trimming white spaces in regex in a line from start to end using regex

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regex.I'm trying to understand the concept of trimming the white spaces in the line.In the process i came across this snippet

Below given is the example:
 http://regexone.com/example/5

The question has got a solution as well

```
 ^\s*([\w\s.]*)\s*$
```

However..i am finding it hard to understand this.Let me explain my understanding till now

```
 ^   - Starting of the line
\s*  - WhiteSpace
[\w\s.]*- Combination of a word character and white space character??(Zero 
          or more times??)(Have not understood properly)
 \s*  -Again a whitespace character(Zero or more times?)
 $   -End of the line
```

I am able to understand the syntax but couldnot understand it's complete sense.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks about right. I will try to clarify

```
 ^       - Start of the line
\s       - Single whitespace character (space or tab or line return)
*        - 0 or more of the previous item
\s*      - Zero or more whitespace characters
[]       - Character class. Matches any of the characters or groups of characters
           contained
[\w\s.]  - Matches a word character, a whitespace character or a period ('.')
[\w\s.]* - Matches 0 or more of the above
 $       - End of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

`\s*` , zero or more white space so this would match continuous spaces.Why we use start instead of plus means continuous spaces may or maynot present. Likewise the same applies to the character class `[\w\s.]*` which may match a word char or space or dot zero or more times ie, it would match `foo       bar.buzz` because all the alphanumeric chars plus underscore are considered as word characters which are matched by `\w` and the inbetween spaces are matched by `\s` and the last final dot was matched by `.`. `[\w\s.]*` repeats the combination of patterns `\w`, `\s`, `.` zero or more times. Note that `[\w\s.]` alone would match a single char only.

[Play with this site to understand how regex works.](https://regex101.com/r/tN3cE0/1)